# How to send query string parameters using supertest?

Tags: supertest

I'm using supertest to send get query string parameters, how can I do that?

I tried

```
var imsServer = supertest.agent("https://example.com");

imsServer.get("/")
  .send({
    username: username,
    password: password,
    client_id: 'Test1',
    scope: 'openid,TestID',
    response_type: 'token',
    redirect_uri: 'https://example.com/test.jsp'
  })
  .expect(200) 
  .end(function (err, res) {
    // HTTP status should be 200
    expect(res.status).to.be.equal(200);
    body = res.body;
    userId = body.userId;
    accessToken = body.access_token;
    done();
  });
```

but that didn't send the parameters `username`, `password`, `client_id` as query string to the endpoint. Is there a way to send query string parameters using supertest?

Answer (score 139):

Although [`supertest`](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) is not that well documented, you can have a look into the [`tests/supertest.js`](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/blob/master/test/supertest.js).

There you have a [test suite](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/blob/master/test/supertest.js#L1038) only for the query strings.

Something like:

```
request(app)
  .get('/')
  .query({ val: 'Test1' })
  .expect(200, function(err, res) {
    res.text.should.be.equal('Test1');
    done();
  });
```

Therefore:

```
.query({
  key1: value1,
  ...
  keyN: valueN
})
```

should work.

Comment: how silly that this simple function is not mentioned in the README. Makes me wonder if I am misunderstanding something about supertest.

Comment: @vinhboy Thats probably because supertest is just `superagent` with the added expect() function. If you look in superagent's docs https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/ you can see the query function described with examples.

Comment: Update 2020, .query({k:v}) doesn't work with sails 1.0 and supertest 4.0.2. I had to ```.post('/users/data/?lang=in')``` to make it work

Comment: @imsheth if you're using `post()`, then the corresponding function is `send()`, not `query()`. For example, try `.post('/users/data').send('lang=in')`.

Answer (score -1):

it is not the best way but you also can do this:

```
await supertest(BASE_URL)
      .get(`/?search=${Title}&`)
```